# When clicked submit button, php does not work, shows the code, but does not send email

Tags: php

I am very new to coding. Created a form watching a YouTube video.

But when I click submit button, php does not work, shows the php code, but does not send email. Would greatly appreciate your help. Went through numerous responses on Stackoverflow could not figure it out. Thanks in advance.

```
<html>
<head>

<title> Contact Form Design </title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
<div class="contact-title">
<h1> Say Hello</h1>
<h2> We are</h2>
</div>
<div class="contact-form">
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contact-form-handler.php">
<input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" required>
<br>
<input name="mail" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your email" required>
<br>
<textarea name="message"class="form-control" placeholder="Message" row="4" required></textarea><br>
<input type="submit" class="form-control submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">
</form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST ['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_from = 'noreply@thiraya.lk';
$email_subject = "New Form Submission";
$email_body = "User Name: $name.\n".
        "User Email: $visitor_email.\n".
        "User Message: $message.\n";

$to = "roshaanr@gradientalliance.com";

$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers = "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";

mail ($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
header ("Location: index2020.html");

?>`
```

Comment: What is the extension of the file? Did you set up a php server to serve the page? Your issue is caused by either one or the other point.

Comment: - extension is .php
- "Did you set up a php server to serve the page? " - i saved the ,php and .html file on my live server

Comment: And the live server is setup to handle php?

Comment: I see. Let me check on this. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you just created a `form.php` file and a `submit.php` file. You then call the first one directly from your local disk on an url that looks like `file://my/path/to/my/file/form.php` so it cannot work.

In order to run PHP scripts, you have to run a webserver that handles PHP, such as Apache (you can also use nginx or others I don't know).

## Windows

If you are using Windows you can install tools that provide directly a webserver, a mysql server (to handle database) and even fake mail server.

#### WAMP

WAMP is an accronym for Windows Apache Mysql PHP. You can [download it here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/) and install it. It is a simple way to start an http server that handles PHP.

#### Laragon

[Laragon](https://laragon.org/) is like WAMP, a windows software that install Apache, Mysql and PHP for you. You don't have to setup a lot of things. Laragon also brings you some tools like cmder, node and installer for wordpress, laravel projects and so on.

## Linux

If you're under linux you would certainly prefer to install apache, mysql and php from your packet manager. Then it all depends on your linux distribution. I let you find the commands and the resources to do it then.

## macOS

If you are a macOS user I think you can use some tools like [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/).

Comment: Yes, i just created a .php file. No idea about Apache. Will use your MAMP and check it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your file php.ini
Look for `[mail function]`
and enter the following for example:

```
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
sendmail_from = <yourEmailAdress>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Sorry to say when you say "configure your file php.ini " I have no clue how to do this. 

I created a php file on dreamviewer, saved as .php  and uploaded it to my live server

Comment: On your live server you should have a file php.ini at the root of it

Comment: I saved the file as 
contact-form-handler.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is your problem:

> "... when I click submit button, php does not work, shows the php code ..."

Your webserver is not correctly configured to execute php code and it only shows your php code as a simple html page. Take a look at your webserver configuration and check if php is correctly installed in your system.

Search for docs, examples and tutorials on internet about how to install php you can find lots of them.

For example:
[Install php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php)